# Bibliography: How can I change the "&" in "and" in the references?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apacite

Is it possible to change the author separator "&" into "and" in the reference list? I am writing my master dissertation using:

`\usepackage{apacite}
 \usepackage[round]{natbib}
 \bibliographystyle{apacite}`

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. To maximize the interoperability of  the `apacite` and `natbib` packages, they should *no*t be loaded separately. Instead, do run `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` (and don't run `\usepackage[round]{natbib}`).

Answer (score 3):

The bibtex style inserts `\BBA` for "and" and `apacite.sty` defines the macro, ultimately depending on these definitions

```
\newcommand{\BBAA}{\&}  % between authors in parenthetical cites and ref. list
\newcommand{\BBAB}{and} % between authors in in-text citation
\newcommand{\BAnd}{\&}  % for ``Ed. \& Trans.'' in ref. list
```

so for example you could use

```
\renewcommand{\BBAA}{and}  % between authors in parenthetical cites and ref. list
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't change. I have also used the \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} command instead of loading natbib and apacite separately @Mico